# Outsystems - binary data to image widget

Tags: outsystems

I have an image (binary data from some REST API) and I need to show it to my user. Is there another way than inserting it into a (temporary) database table?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the link here https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/21614/showing-image-in-a-variable-to-image-widget/

Comment: Thanks. This has worked.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments on the question, the answer can be found [here](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/21614/showing-image-in-a-variable-to-image-widget/) on the OutSystems forum.

> In the preparation of this Page I load the binary data, and at the end of the Preparation I set a Download instead of an End or Navigate. And you got to make sure that the Download has the Save to Disk property set to 'No'

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, to creating a temporary database and the one presented in the forum, is to use  a Local Variable and having the "Image Content" pointed to that local variable and type of the image as "Binary Data".

The following images depict the process above.

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!